# compare and filter values in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a csv file containing telephone numbers.

There is about 15 numbers with the area code +44 and 20 numbers beginning with +64 (there are about 40 area codes). i need to echo one number of each set and drop the remains.

i loaded all the content using fgetcsv(). but i cant find a way to do the filtering part. can some please give me an idea how to sort this out in php?

Comment: What about area codes that have one or three letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replace  $numbers with your csv file content.

```
$numbers = array('+1134124', '+11412421', '+41125125','+41125124','+41125144','+41155124','+44125124','+44155124');                          

$final = array();

$received = array();

foreach($numbers as $snKey => $snValue )
{

    $snCode = substr($snValue,0,3);

    if(in_array($snCode,$received))
        continue;
    else
    {
        $received[] = $snCode;
        $final[] = $snValue;
    }
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = array('+1134124', '+11412421', '+41125125', …);

$filtered = array_reduce($numbers, function ($f, $num) {
    return $f + array(substr($num, 0, 3) => $num);
}, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter them while read line from the file

like:

```
 $array = array(); 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $prefix = substr($data, 0, 3);
            if(in_array($prefix, $array))
               continue;
            else{
               $array[] = prefix;
               # save the line or echo
            } 

     }
```